# Sed command for masking credit card upto 12 digit

Tags: unix, sed

problem:

Given  lines of credit card numbers, mask the first 12 digits of each credit card number with an asterisk (i.e., *) and print the masked card number on a new line. Each credit card number consists of four space-separated groups of four digits. For example, the credit card number 1234 5678 9101 1234 would be masked and printed as **** **** **** 1234.

How we can able to do it with sed command, I'm not getting how to deal with spaces?
Please help me out!

**Sample Input**

```
1234 5678 9101 1234  
2999 5178 9101 2234
```

**Sample Output**

```
**** **** **** 1234
**** **** **** 2234
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Akshay, on SO we do encourage users to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem so kindly do add the same in your question with CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Comment: you can match first 14 characters and replace it with `**** **** ****`

Comment: yeah sudeep great idea, I never thought with 14 characters, lets try me to this...

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  it works fine -> sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] /**** /g'  anyone have better solution, please provide your guidance.

Comment: Please add multiple sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus I'll edit the question Sorry for that, I'm new user on SO...,again sorry for your inconvenience.

Comment: @AkshaySingh if there's no space after the last digit, then yes, yours is good solution.. you can add it as an answer yourself too

Comment: @Sudeep yes there is no space after last digit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
$ echo -e "hello
1234 5678 9101 1234
2999 5178 9101 2234
something else" | sed -E "s/^[0-9]{4} [0-9]{4} [0-9]{4} ([0-9]{4})\b/**** **** **** \1/g"
hello
**** **** **** 1234
**** **** **** 2234
something else
```

If you want to preserve the possibility of spaces ...

```sh
$ echo -e "hello
1234567891011234
2999 5178 9101 2234
something else" | sed -E "s/^[0-9]{4}(\s*)[0-9]{4}(\s*)[0-9]{4}(\s*)([0-9]{4})\b/****\1****\2****\3\4/g"
hello
************1234
**** **** **** 2234
something else
```

If you always want intermediate spaces in the output (even if not in the input), then replace `\1`, `\2`, and `\3` with literal spaces.

Comment: what is the meaning of ->{4}<- this? I can understand -E option to combined multiple sed commands but didn't get this ?

Comment: `{4}` number of time previous char should be repeated. In this case 4 digits

Comment: occurs exactly 4 times; `{2,7}` occurs between 2 and 7 times

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] /**** /g'`

Explanation: Substitute "multiple digits followed by space" by "**** ".

Last 4 digits aren't followed by space, hence, won't be replaced by asterisk.

Comment: Please read [answer] and remember you are not only answering the question, but also educating any (future) readers of this post. This, please [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code works.

Comment: Very nice solution but please explain the essential detail.

Comment: Ammm, we can also do this but using awk:  awk '{print "****","****","****",$4}'

Comment: Even this can also work, and I think this would be more shorter sed =>  sed -r 's/[0-9]{4} /**** /g' same thing but different way.....!, I enjoyed this one.